# WordPress Permalink setting is not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I was working on a WordPress [website](http://amouraffairs.in/) . I am getting problem regarding the permalink. I am unable to change it. Whenever I changed it and applied save, then it automatically changed to "default". I chacked my .htaccess file, changes its permissions, Even I edited this file. but nothing good happened. Please help me.

I changed my .htaccess code as below :

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question and more suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: it is programming and regular expressions.